# Impossible install Packeges or Dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies

I'm trying to solve a problem with unity login which breaks something and I'm not able install/remove any packages. If I try to install a package with `apt-get install package-name` or try to install missing dependencies with `apt-get install -f` the result is the same as shown below.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libboost-iostreams1.54.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libcwidget3 but it is not going to be installed
libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd-services (= 204-5ubuntu20.27)
Breaks: libpam-systemd:i386 (!= 204-5ubuntu20.27) but 204-5ubuntu20.25 is to be installed
libpam-systemd:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libcap2:i386 (>= 2.10) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libcgmanager0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libnih-dbus1:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libnih1:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libpam0g:i386 (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
Breaks: libpam-systemd (!= 204-5ubuntu20.25) but 204-5ubuntu20.27 is to be installed
libsystemd-daemon0 : Breaks: libsystemd-daemon0:i386 (!= 204-5ubuntu20.27) but 204-5ubuntu20.25 is to be installed
libsystemd-daemon0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
Breaks: libsystemd-daemon0 (!= 204-5ubuntu20.25) but 204-5ubuntu20.27 is to be installed
systemd-services:i386 : Depends: libacl1:i386 (>= 2.2.51-8) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libcap2:i386 (>= 2.10) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libcgmanager0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libnih-dbus1:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libnih1:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libselinux1:i386 (>= 2.0.65) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libudev1:i386 (>= 183) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: systemd-shim:i386 (>= 3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

Whatever I try to install/remove I have the same putout. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Yes i tried ....and the result is the same...

Comment: What is the output of `lsb_release -a`?  What happens when you do `sudo apt-get update`?  Did you install software or attempt to upgrade or change anything prior to this set of errors showing up?

Answer (score 0):

Basically after an update unity crashed everytime we tried to login. The problems seems was related to compiz. we had installed Gnome Desktop but we still have problems to login.

Looking in some forum they had installed some library....and from that moment we cannot use anymore apt-get install....or remove.....

Answer (score 0):

....magically this morning apt-get works again.....and i don't know why...

the only things i did i removed google repository because of a gpg error during the apt-get update, i didn't realized what magically was fixed...

Then i  run apt-get install -f that  removed a lot of packages included Network-Manager and apt-get autoremove...

we have reinstalled unity and added Gnome as desktop manager. Seems to works even if there is something strange. In Some profile if you use unity the upper bar is the one used by gnome rather then unity itself.
But we didn't touch.....to worry to broke again something..